# What is the difference between 要求事項 and 要件?

Tags: word-choice

What could be the difference between 要求事項｛ようきゅうじこう｝ and 要件｛ようけん｝?

And what would make more sense, 法的要求事項 or 法的要件. Are they the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

> 要求事項: items/things that someone or something demands or claims
>
> 要件: necessary condition, requirement

要求{ようきゅう} has the implied meaning of 'order', so you shouldn't use this phrase without a good reason. For example, 卒業{そつぎょう}要件 (graduation requirements) can't be alternatively written as 卒業要求事項.

When it comes to 法的{ほうてき}要求事項 and 法的要件, 法{ほう} (law) is not a person and its requirements can be treated as orders. Therefore, both of these phrases are possible. While 法的要件 means just 'legal requirement', 法的要求事項 sounds like very firm requirements imposed by the law. Practically, they indicate the same thing, though.